# Use GCC to Create New DLL

Tags: windows, gcc, dll, cygwin

I'm using cygwin and gcc to create a new dll on Windows XP.  I have an existing dll (MyCApi.dll) and example_wrap.o that I want to both use to create a new dll, example.dll.  I ran the below gcc command and it looks like gcc can't find MyCApi.dll.  I have the directory it lives in on my path.  Is there something else I need to do?

```
$ gcc -shared example_wrap.o -mno-cygwin -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -lMyCApi -o example.dll
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lMyCApi
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say it's on your path (LIBRARY_PATH?) but I suspect if you add

```
-L/directory/where/dll/lives
```

to the compilation line it'll work just fine.